# What is the most comprehensive website for booking parking spots in Munich/Bavaria?

Tags: automobiles, munich, bavaria

For work purposes I need to stay in a suburban city near Munich that has very limited public transport. I am therefore using a car to get around.

Occasionally I need to drive into Munich city center and therefore need a place to park. So far I've been using a site called [Ampido](https://www.ampido.com/) for reserving a parking spot, but I strongly suspect it's far from comprehensive as I've seen plenty of parking garages not mentioned there. Likewise Google Maps doesn't have a lot of parking spots. So the question is - **what is the most comprehensive website for reserving/booking parking spaces in Munich?**

I could obviously park on the street and pay at the parking meter, but the ones in Munich only seem to accept coins which is inconvenient. Likewise I could find a parking spot somewhere in outer Munich and take the S-Bahn, but I prefer to have a predictable place to park rather than circling around town looking for a free spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the most comprehensive website for reserving/booking parking
>   spaces in Munich?

I honestly don't think there is one. Parking in Munich is usually either difficult or expensive.

In the city centre, there are plenty of parking garages, which mostly have free places and don't require any reservation or booking. You can find them on Google Maps if you search for 'Parkhaus'. The rates are usually around 3-4€/h, often with a daily cap in the range 25-40€. Most, if not all, of the parking garages accept card payments.

Parking on the street is difficult in most parts of Munich, not only in the city centre. Inside the 'Mittlerer Ring' (ring road) you will almost only find metered or residents-only parking. Metered parking is often limited only to a few hours. There are also several parking zones, where parking regulations are posted on a sign where you enter the zone (and not on every street). In some parts of the old city and city centre, a curb colouring system is used. Metered parking is allowed where there is a blue curb marking. Even in the outskirts, it can often be very difficult to find a free parking spot on the street, especially in office or industrial areas.

Even if you exclude the option in your question, do you know the Park+Ride system in Munich? In the outskirts, there are many so called Park+Ride facilities (marked with a 'P+R' sign). These are larger parking lots or parking garages close to subway or suburban train stations. Rates are relatively moderate and usually around 1.00-1.50€/day or 10-15€ for a monthly ticket. You can find a [map of all parking lots, rates and conditions here](http://www.parkundride.de/en/parken.html).

Comment: "Parking in Munich is usually either difficult or expensive." - on Ampido I've  been parking for a whole day for 6 euros, near Ostbahnhof. Pretty cheap if you ask me. But thanks for mentioning the P+R system - it's extremely horrible in Prague so I didn't think about it in Munich.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know how easy it is to find a free spot, but since street parking is free near Ostbahnhof, I guess parking garages in the area can't charge arbitrary high rates. As a comparison, the nearby P+R garage at Innsbrucker Ring charge 1.50€/day or 17€ for a monthly ticket.

Comment: My only problem with the P+Rs is that they don't seem to take anything except coins. I should probably get a 10 pack of parking tickets instead.